# How to count the number of times "." appears in a webpage?

Tags: java, html

I want to scan through an html page and count the number of times "." (period) shows up. Here I have some code that reads the html, and prints out the desired output.

I was thinking to modify this code, but seeing as this is a straightforward question, perhaps we don't need to go through the trouble of modifying it; rather, we can just go straight to coding a new program.

Here's the code where I read the html of a webpage (a lot of it should be unnecessary code):

```
import edu.duke.*;


public class URLFinder {
    public StorageResource findURLs(String url) {
        URLResource page = new URLResource(url);
        String source = page.asString();
        StorageResource store = new StorageResource();
        int start = 0;
        while (true) {
            int index = source.indexOf("href=", start);
            if (index == -1) {
                break;
            }
            int firstQuote = index+6; // after href="
            int endQuote = source.indexOf("\"", firstQuote);
            String sub = source.substring(firstQuote, endQuote);
            if (sub.contains(".")) {
                store.add(sub);
            }
            start = endQuote + 1;
        }
        return store;
    }

    public void testURL() {
        StorageResource s1 = findURLs("http://www.dukelearntoprogram.com/course2/data/newyorktimes.html");
        //StorageResource s2 = findURLs("http://www.doctorswithoutborders.org");
        for (String link : s1.data()) {
            System.out.println(link);
        }
        System.out.println("size = " + s1.size());
        //System.out.println("size = " + s2.size());
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the HTML contained within the `source` variable?

Comment: For the java guys answering question: Note that stuff can be added into web page using `css`, `javascript` etc at client side ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
int count = 0;
for (char c : source.toCharArray()) {
    if (c == '.') {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, utilize the [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#countMatches%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) library and its great StringUtils functions: `StringUtils.countMatches(String string, String subStringToCount)`. You would then just do `StringUtils.countMatches(source, ".");` to get the count of periods.

If you were putting this into your current program, you'd want to edit your `findUrls` function, inserting the counting right after `String source = page.asString();`.

Or if you just wanted this in its own function:

```
public int countPeriods(String url) {
    URLResource page = new URLResource(url);
    String source = page.asString();
    int count = 0;
    for (char c : source.toCharArray()) {
        if (c == '.') {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

where now all you would need to do is pass in a url as a string to the function and it would return you your count.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to use the `indexOf` method:

```
int index = -1;
int count = 0;
String source = ...;
while((index = source.indexOf(".", ++index) != -1)
    count++
```

As pointed out by @TJCrowder, it might be the case that you need to let some script execute. If that is the case, please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961965/accessing-html-generated-by-javascript-with-htmlunit-java) previous SO question.